# How can I find the error in my getline function?

Tags: c++

I'm new to the getline function in C++.

I'm writing a simple program that creates a struct for a Fraction, which reads in a numerator and denominator. Then, I'm writing a `void printFraction()` function which takes in the struct as a parameter and outputs the numerator divided by the denominator.

However, I'm getting an error that says that there is no matching function for `getline`, and that it requires arguments but is only getting 2. How can I find what the problem is?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

void printFraction(Fraction f);
int main() {
    Fraction f;
    cout << "Please enter numerator";
    getline(cin, f.numerator);
    cout << "Please enter denominator";
    getline(cin, f.denominator);
    cin.ignore();
    printFraction(f);
}

void printFraction(Fraction f) {
    cout << f.numerator << "/" << f.denominator;
}
```

Comment: `getline` is for getting a whole input line as a string, not as `int`. If you want formatted input use `cin >>`, e.g. `cin >> f.numerator;`

Answer (score 6):

First thing, you must include `string`:

```
#include <string>
```

Also, `getline` doesn't work with `int`. So you'll have to take in a `std::string` and then convert that `string` into `int`.

Consider not using the following in your code:

```
using namespace std;
```

..as it's considered as bad practice. For more info on why, look up to [why is "using namespace std" considered as a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

So after all these fixes, here's the final code:

### Final Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct Fraction {

    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

void printFraction(Fraction f);

int main() {

    Fraction f;
    std::string numerator, denominator;

    std::cout << "Please enter numerator: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, numerator);

    std::cout << "Please enter denominator: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, denominator);

    f.numerator = std::stoi(numerator);
    f.denominator = std::stoi(denominator);

    printFraction(f);
}

void printFraction(Fraction f) {

    std::cout << f.numerator << '/' << f.denominator;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So, you can't use `getline` on an integer `int`, it reads the entire line as a string. Therefore you can either use std::cin for input or convert your line into an integer by doing the following

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;    
 
struct Fraction {    
        int numerator;
        int denominator;
};    

void printFraction(Fraction f);    

int main() {    
        Fraction f;
        string line;

        cout << "Please enter numerator";
        getline(cin, line);
        f.numerator = stoi(line); // stoi() converts a string to an integer

        cout << "Please enter denominator";
        getline(cin, line);
        f.denominator = stoi(line);
        cin.ignore();

        printFraction(f);
 
}    
 
void printFraction(Fraction f) {    
        cout << f.numerator << "/" << f.denominator;
}
```

Comment: `#include<string>`

Comment: `using namespace std` is not a good practice. You should mention that too.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

First of all include the string library

```
#include <string>
```

secondly `getline` is used to read inputs in string format hence the error and third don't `using namespace std;` it is considered a bad programming practice.

**Solution**

After obtaining the user input in string format use `stoi` to convert the variable to an integer that will enable you to perform arithmetic operations

I have modified your code down below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

   
struct Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};

void printFraction(Fraction f);


int main() {
    Fraction f;
    std::string numerator, denominator;

    std::cout << "Please enter numerator";
    std::getline(cin, numerator);

    std::cout << "Please enter denominator";
    std::getline(cin, denominator);

    f.numerator = std::stoi(numerator);
    f.denominator = std::stoi(denominator);

    printFraction(f);
}

void printFraction(Fraction f) {
    std::cout << f.numerator << "/" << f.denominator;
}
```

**References**

[stoi() C++](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/)

[getline() C++](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)